# Find the limit and show that it converges to that limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $\{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n}\}$. Find the limit and prove it converges to that limit or prove that it does not converge.
My attempt:

$(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-n=\sqrt{n^2+n}-n$

Multiplying by the conjugate then dividing by it gives:

$\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}+1}$.

Then taking the limit of this gives 1/2.

To prove that the sequence converges to 1/2, I have to show that $|(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{2}|<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. I know that I have to find an index $N<\epsilon$ but that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Just work with the equivalent expression which you found: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Just work with the equivalent expression which you found: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}+1}$

Take an arbitrary $\epsilon$

Find N such that
$|\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}+1} - \frac{1}{2}|<\epsilon$

when $n \gt N$

Answer (score 1):

Verify that $|(\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n) \sqrt n -\frac 1 2|=\frac 1 { 2(\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n)^{2}}$. This gives $ |(\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n) \sqrt n -\frac 1 2|<\frac  1{2n} <\epsilon$ for $n >\frac 1 {2\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use that

$$\left|(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\frac12\left|\frac{\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\right|=$$

$$=\frac12 \frac1{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)^2} \le\frac1{8n}$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:  Can you use the binomial theorem?

\begin{aligned}\sqrt{n}\big(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n\big) &= n\Bigg(\Big(1 + \frac{1}{n}\Big)^{1/2}-1\Bigg) \\
&=\Bigg(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8n}+\cdots\Bigg)
\end{aligned}

Gives a handle on the error term and therefore a route to find $N$ needed to make the error less than $\varepsilon$